# could not run the cronjob in ruby using wheneverize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

I have followed this link https://github.com/javan/whenever but I tried to run the cronjob in development mode it is not working. I would like to know in the below lines:

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"       
  rake "my:rake:task"                 
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end
```

What is `MyModel.some_process`?

If I want to run a ruby file I have written this way

```
every 1.minute do
  runner "cronjob.rb",:environment => "development"
end
```

... is it the correct way or do I have to specify the path of the `cronjob.rb` file like:

```
runner "app/controllers/cronjob.rb"
```

Where can I see the output for rake and command?

Answer (score 2):

See more on runner here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner.

According to it, it runs a Ruby code in the context of the application. Or so to say you could execute some method for a model(which whenever documentation tries to show). This would be slightly different in Rails-2. Also if you see the whenever documentation for the default job_types, for example for job_type runner it does the following-

```
"cd :path && script/rails runner -e :environment ':task' :output"
```

So when you do `runner "MyModel.some_process"` in `schedule.rb` it would go to the application path and execute `script/rails runner -e <development specified by you> MyModel.some_process`, in-short it executes `MyModel.some_process`. Hope this helps!